# What is the value of size to be provided for the getc method in xmodem protocol?

Tags: python, xmodem

I'm trying to transfer a file using the **XMODEM** protocol.

I saw and did not understand the solution provided in: [Can I use the xmodem protocol with PySerial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834247/can-I-use-the-xmodem-protocol-with-pyserial)

I saw [xmodem package link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmodem).

1. What is the value of `size` to be provided for the `getc` method? It is not assigned with any value given in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834247/can-I-use-the-xmodem-protocol-with-pyserial).
2. When I use simple method as explained in the [second link](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmodem), I end up getting the error: `No handlers could be found for logger "xmodem"`.

Here is my code to send the file.

```
import serial
from xmodem import XMODEM, CRC
from time import sleep
def getc(size, timeout=1):
    return port.read(size)
def putc(data, timeout=1):
    port.write(data)
    sleep(0.001) # give device time to send ACK
port = serial.Serial(port='COM10',parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,timeout=0,xonxoff=0,rtscts=0,dsrdtr=0,baudrate=9600)

sleep(2) # give device time to handle command
stream = open('..\\stream\\myfile.bin','rb')
modem = XMODEM(getc, putc)
modem.send(stream, quiet = 0)
```

I get the error: `No handlers could be found for logger "xmodem"`.

Comment: The _"error"_ `No handlers could be found for logger "xmodem"` is not really an error. It is just the `xmodem` package warning you that it is trying to output a log message but there is not logger `xmodem` configured. See: [logging package documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).

Comment: @PedroRomano - Thanks a lot for your reply.
You gave me solution for my 2nd question.
Here is the solution for 1st question, **getc** and **putc** are used by XMODEM to read _size_ number of bytes from port and write _data_ to port respectively. They need to be defined by user and supplied to XMODEM object. XMODEM internally calls **getc** with _size_. 
Regards,
Manju

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for 1st question, **getc** and **putc** are used by XMODEM to read *size* number of bytes from port and write *data* to port respectively. They need to be defined by user and supplied to XMODEM object. XMODEM internally calls **getc** with *size*.